# Вступление в группы и чаты telegram

Tags: telegram, telethon

У меня есть большое количество ссылок на группы в телеграм, и мне нужно автоматизировать вступление в эти группы. Все ссылки, что нашёл, ведут на отсутствующую страницу документации telethon

Answer (score 0):

```
async def enter_chat(client, group_name):
        col = 0
        group_close = ''
        for i in group_name:
            if col == 1:
                    group_close += i
            if i == '+':
                    col = 1
        if col != 1:
            group_open = group_name
            try:
                result = await client(JoinChannelRequest(group_open))
            except ValueError:
                result = "Error"
    
        else:
            try:
                result = await client(ImportChatInviteRequest(group_close))
            except ValueError:
                result = "Error"
        return result
    group_list = ['t.me/kaluga_kurilkavoz'] # имя группы, id канала, или хэш закрытой группы , списком
        otvet_list = []
        otvet_mas = []
        csv_message = []
        for group_name in group_list:
            otvet_list.append(await enter_chat(client, group_name))
        for result in range(len(otvet_list)):
            if isinstance(otvet_list[result], Updates):
                otvet = "Группа \"" + str(otvet_list[result].chats[0].title) + "\" успешно добавлена"
            else:
                otvet = "Добавление группы \"" + group_list[result]+ "\" завершилось с ошибкой"
            otvet_mas.append(otvet)
        for x in otvet_mas:
            print(x)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]